# Mapping with composite key over relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I would like to know if it is possible to use JoinColumn giving a referenced column of a related object.

I have something simlar to:

```
public class A {

  @ManyToOne
  private C c;

  @Column(name = "KEY_THAT_B_WILL_USE_CONTAINED_IN_A")
  private String key_that_B_will_use; 

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<B> myBs = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class B {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "KEY_THAT_B_WILL_USE_CONTAINED_IN_A",
            referencedColumnName = "KEY_THAT_B_WILL_USE_CONTAINED_IN_A"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "KEY_THAT_B_WILL_USE_CONTAINED_IN_C", referencedColumnName = "C.KEY_THAT_B_WILL_USE_CONTAINED_IN_C")
    })
}

public class C {
  @Column(name = "KEY_THAT_B_WILL_USE_CONTAINED_IN_C")
  private String key_that_B_will_use; 
}
```

Of course in class C, referencedColumnName = "C.KEY_THAT_B_WILL_USE_CONTAINED_IN_C" won't work.

But how do I create a reference which such a model that I can not change?

Thanks :-)

Comment: Read the Hibernate docs. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated

Comment: Please add some primary key indicators (i.e. `@Id` annotations) to the classes. Also, `B` is missing an actual field for its `@ManyToOne` annotation (presumably `a`).

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have :-). I could use JoinFormula but it issues an exception with Spring Boot which is opened and which is not fixed. I also do not really like this JoinFormula. And with an EmbeddedId, I do not see how to get to what I want to do.

Comment: What do you mean by KEY_THAT_B_WILL_USE_CONTAINED_IN_C? Please show the DB model

Comment: In the end, I have done it changing the data model to have it easier...And with JoinColumns, it just work.